# Use success() or complete() in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to understand the AJAX call below, in terms of the `complete()` method;

When I replace `complete()` with `success()`, I get an empty *responseText* just  as with the AJAX `error()` method.

On the other hand, when I leave the `complete()` method there as it is, everything works as expected.

Is it that `success()` returns earlier than `complete()`?

```
$("#formnaw").submit(function() {
  var fnc = invoerFnc.attr("value");
  var vnaam = invoerVnaam.attr("value");
  var anaam = invoerAnaam.attr("value");
  var str1 = invoerStr1.attr("value");
  var nr1 = invoerNr1.attr("value");
  var pc1 = invoerPc1.attr("value");
  var pl1 = invoerPl1.attr("value");
  var tel1 = invoerTel1.attr("value");
  var mob1 = invoerMob1.attr("value");
  var em1 = invoerEm1.attr("value");
  var goknop = $("#formnaw > .instelling_go");
  //we deactiveren de submit knop tijdens het verzenden 
  goknop.attr({
    disabled: true
  });
  goknop.blur();
  //stuur de post variabelen naar livetabs.php
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "registraties/instellingenact.php",
    data: "actie=wijzignaw&vnaam=" + vnaam + "&anaam=" + anaam + "&functie=" + fnc + "&straat=" + str1 + "&nr=" + nr1 + "&postcode=" + pc1 + "&plaats=" + pl1 + "&tel=" + tel1 + "&mob=" + mob1 + "&email=" + em1,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        alert('bij success');
        //doe iets
      } //EINDE success
      ,
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
          //doe iets
        } else if (textStatus == 'error') {
          //doe iets
        }
        //her-activeer de zend knop
        goknop.attr({
          disabled: false
        });
      } //EINDE error
      ,
    complete: function(data) {
        updatelijst.append(data.responseText + "<br>");
        if (data.responseText.indexOf("Fout") != -1) {
          $('#formnaw').find('td.foutnr1').prepend(data.responseText);
        } else {
          updatelijst.animate({
            opacity: 'show'
          }, 1000, function() {});
        }
        //her-activeer de zend knop
        goknop.attr({
          disabled: false
        });
      } //EINDE complete
  }); //EINDE ajax
  //we stoppen het standaard gedrag van een submit, zodat de pagina niet wordt vernieuwd.
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 106):

> Is it that `success()` returns earlier than `complete()`?

**Yes**; the AJAX `success()` method runs before the `complete()` method.

Below is a diagram illustrating the process flow:

[image: AJAX call process flow diagram.]

It is important to note that

- The `success()` (Local Event) is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).
- On the other hand, the `complete()` (Local Event) is called regardless of if the request was successful, or not. You will always receive a complete callback, even for synchronous requests.

*... more details on AJAX Events [here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).*

Answer (score 61):

`complete` executes after either the `success` or `error` callback were executed.

Maybe you should check the second parameter `complete` offers too. It's a String holding the type of success the ajaxCall had.

The different callbacks are described a little more in detail here [`jQuery.ajax( options )`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)

---

I guess you missed the fact that the `complete` and the `success` function (I know inconsistent API) get different data passed in. `success` gets only the data, `complete` gets the whole `XMLHttpRequest` object. Of course there is no `responseText` property on the data string.

So if you replace `complete` with `success` you also have to replace `data.responseText` with `data` only.

**success**

> The function gets passed two
>   arguments: The data returned from the
>   server, formatted according to the
>   'dataType' parameter, and a string
>   describing the status.

**complete**

> The function gets passed two
>   arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object
>   and a string describing the type of
>   success of the request.

If you need to have access to the whole `XMLHttpRequest` object in the success callback I suggest trying this.

```
var myXHR = $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data, status) {
        ...do whatever with myXHR; e.g. myXHR.responseText...
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: oops, comment came at the same time
So, if I get this right. The complete function contains all the information I need. Success contains less unless you pass two arguments in the function. I hope I am not getting stupid, but is complete like I used then not enough all the time? Or is it that success is more lightweight??

Comment: Also in addition to my last comment, will my code from above still cath the error. In short, will it do everything without any drawbacks if I leave out the success option. Sorry if it's sounding like I don't understand it yet. It's a little confusing to me.

Comment: I edited my question to contain the complete code I used
It doesn't give any errors, but I can probably cut the success option out. If the result is the same.

Comment: complete gets the whole XMLHttpRequest object. success gets content of the XMLHttpRequest.responseText property. Your code above should work without the success callback too, without any sideeffects as it does nothing anyway.

But there is a difference in using success or complete. Success only gets called when the request completed successfully. But the complete callback fires on success and on error. Check out http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events to understand better in which order and under which circumstances which callbacks are executed by jquery

Answer (score 13):

"complete" executes when the ajax call is finished. "success" executes when the ajax call finishes with a successful response code.

Comment: thanks,but to be clear, do I have to use the code to execute under a complete option and not under success. And will the error option also work with the complete option alone?

Comment: or, it suggests that I do not get a success responsecode, strange?

Answer (score 7):

Well, speaking from quarantine, the `complete()` in $.ajax is like `finally` in try catch block.

If you use try catch block in any programming language, it doesn't matter whether you execute a thing successfully or got an error in execution. the finally{} block will always be executed.

Same goes for `complete()` in $.ajax, whether you get `success()` response or `error()` the `complete()` function always will be called once the execution has been done.