# ajax jquery with codeigniter. url doesnt access controller

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and cannot get my ajax to work.
I am trying to make links load content into the main document on click.
I looked for instructions but could not figure it out. All works except the ajax returns `alert('ERROR')` message. nothing is loadded into `<div id='load_here'></div>`
Maybe I am missing something in config.php? Do i have to load some library for this to work? 
Any ideas would be helpfull
//main document link

```
<span id='reg_link_rules'>Link</span>  
<div id='load_here'></div>
```

// controller

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {
   public function hello()
   {
      echo 'hello';
   }
}
```

// jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reg_link_rules').click(function(eve){

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET", 
      url: "register/hello", 

      complete: function(data){
        $('#load_here').html(data);
    },
    error: function(){alert('error');}
    });
  });
});
```

I think the problem is that the ajax url does not access the controller. 
Z:/home/codeigniter/www/register/test    this is where i think it takes me

problem solved, the url needed to be http://codeigniter/index.php/register/hello

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with url: "/register/hello".

Might do the trick.

Usually I do a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
</script>
```

At the beginning of my page and simply

```
base_url+"register/hello"
```

instead

That makes my ajax more reliable, even when / is incorrect.

Comment: i was wondering how to do that, thanks. but this didnt fix the problem

Comment: how cani use php code in .js file. so i need home url code for js file ??

Comment: PHP is commands to your service. Javascript is run in your browser. Above example defines `base_url` before your javascript file is loaded.

Answer (score 6):

```
complete: function(data){
        $('#load_here').html(data);
    },
```

### should be

Just referencing another SO question ... [Use success() or complete() in AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021062/use-succes-or-complete-in-ajaxcall)

```
success: function(data){
        $('#load_here').html(data);
    },
```

AND

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
```

### Should be

unless you want your form vars to be submitted along in the URL.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
```

Comment: GET or POST really doesn't matter here as we are not getting or posting any resource here. but the logic is sound . we need success callback function

Comment: i totally agree, however unless the user has a specific reason to use GET then POST should be used according to best practices.. especially when developing a REST-ful API like i presume he is doing. +1 for clarifying.

Comment: i agree with you , this is best to use for good programming practices.

Comment: thanks for your time. I did try success and complete before but neither worked. could the problem be somewhere else besides my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Hello You should add the base url to the URL Ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET", 
  url: <?php echo base_url();?>"register/hello", 

  complete: function(data){
    $('#load_here').html(data);
},
```

Remember enable the helper URL in the Controller!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to pass the bas_url to ajax file

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var baseurl = <?php echo base_url();?>

    $('#reg_link_rules').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url : baseurl+'index.php/register/hello',
            data : '',
            type: "POST",
           success : function(){


            }
        })
        return false;
    })

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have do add index.php to the string. Like so:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET", 
  url: <?php echo base_url();?>"index.php/register/hello", 

  complete: function(data){
    $('#load_here').html(data);
},
```

But it's all about your config file however. It was the mistake in my case.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure two matter

please put your ajax part as  url: ?php echo base_url();?>"register/hello", and  type: "GET",  and also need to check wheter it is routed the url on config/routes.php.