# Execute function after Ajax call is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to Ajax and I am attempting to use Ajax while using a for loop. After the Ajax call I am running a function that uses the variables created in the Ajax call. The function only executes two times. I think that the Ajax call may not have enough time to make the call before the loop starts over. Is there a way to confirm the Ajax call before running the function printWithAjax()? **I do not want the printWithAjax() function to execute until the Ajax call is complete.** Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var id;
var vname;
function ajaxCall(){
for(var q = 1; q<=10; q++){
 $.ajax({                                            
         url: 'api.php',                        
         data: 'id1='+q+'',                                                         
         dataType: 'json',
         async:false,                    
         success: function(data)          
         {   
            id = data[0];              
            vname = data[1];
         }
      });

       printWithAjax(); 

 }//end of the for statement
}//end of ajax call function
```

Comment: since you are using `asycn:false`(**don't ever use it, if possible**), the print will execute only after the ajax is completed....

Comment: but the correct solution will be is to call the print function within the success callback and pass the id and vname as arguments

Comment: So you want printWithAjax to fire once for each ajax call?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yA8Zu/2/ - do you also want to make sure the ajax request is executed in sequence if not you can remove the `async:false`

Comment: Since your just passing numbers 1 - 10, why not pass an array or range (1-10) to your server and just make one ajax call? Rather then making 10 ajax requests. Also you can loop through the data to control its display.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick help! I have tried each scenario and I am now able to complete more loops. However, it does not finish all 10. I think the correct way to complete this project may be to attempt to use an array as described by Jay.

Comment: You can use "complete" event for that. https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Answer (score 78):

Try this code:

```
var id;
var vname;
function ajaxCall(){
for(var q = 1; q<=10; q++){
 $.ajax({                                            
     url: 'api.php',                        
     data: 'id1='+q+'',                                                         
     dataType: 'json',
     async:false,                    
     success: function(data)          
     {   
        id = data[0];              
        vname = data[1];
     },
    complete: function (data) {
      printWithAjax(); 
     }
    });

  }//end of the for statement
  }//end of ajax call function
```

The "complete" function executes only after the "success" of ajax. So try to call the printWithAjax() on "complete". This should work for you.

Comment: the complete callback executes irrespective of the success / failure of the ajax call

Comment: wrong! complete is called every time https://stackoverflow.com/a/42229704

Comment: "async:false" worked for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 46):

You can use [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) or [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

**`.ajaxComplete()`** fires after completion of each AJAX request on your page.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  yourFunction();
});
```

**`.ajaxStop()`** fires after completion of all AJAX requests on your page.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  yourFunction();
});
```

Comment: No, ajaxComplete is executed early and is practically useless.

Answer (score 18):

Add .done() to your function

```
var id;
var vname;
function ajaxCall(){
for(var q = 1; q<=10; q++){
 $.ajax({                                            
         url: 'api.php',                        
         data: 'id1='+q+'',                                                         
         dataType: 'json',
         async:false,                    
         success: function(data)          
         {   
            id = data[0];              
            vname = data[1];
         }
      }).done(function(){
           printWithAjax(); 
      });



 }//end of the for statement
}//end of ajax call function
```

Comment: done is the same as `success`. you want `".always()"`

Comment: @MichelAyres I thought success will run only if it is successful and done would run no matter what...

Comment: `run no matter what` == `.always()` take a look at [jQuery.ajax handling continue responses: “success:” vs “.done”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done) also ["An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success()"](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Append `.done()` to your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { //use this
  alert("DONE!");
});
```

See the [JQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) for `.done()`

Answer (score 0):

You should set async = false in head.
Use post/get instead of ajax.

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});

```
    $.post({
        url: 'api.php',
        data: 'id1=' + q + '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            id = data[0];
            vname = data[1];

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var id;
var vname;
function ajaxCall(){
for(var q = 1; q<=10; q++){
 $.ajax({  

 url: 'api.php',                        
 data: 'id1='+q+'',                                                         
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data)          
  {

    id = data[0];              
   vname = data[1];
   printWithAjax();
}
      });



}//end of the for statement
  }//end of ajax call function
```