# Run code when POST has completed, and page has loaded in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have this code:

```
$.when($.post(...)).then(function () {
  ...
});
```

Which I want to combine with `$(document).ready(...);` so that the request  starts when the page initializes, and everything inside the `.then` function runs when both the page and the POST request have finished loading.

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens when you just add $(document).ready(...) inside your callback on then

Comment: You can check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283276/execute-function-after-ajax-call-is-complete/23283596#23283596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will produce a promise for when the DOM is loaded.  So, you can use `$.when()` to wait for both promises.  As such, you can do this:

```
$.when($.post(...), jQuery.ready.promise()).then(function(result) {
    // code here
    // result[0] is ajax result
});
```

This will let you launch your ajax call immediately, but then process its results only when the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out.

Apparently `$(document).ready(function () { })` doesn't just set an event handler, but also runs the code inside immediately if the page has already loaded. So now I'm just using this:

```
$.post(...).then(function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

This allows for the code to be run only if the POST request has completed, and the page has finished loading.

Comment: No need for `$.when()` in this code.  It is superfluous since `$.post()` has a `.then()` handler all on its own.  Also, see how `$.when()` can be used in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You, can set either some time interval like

```
setTimeout(function(){ //do something here }, 3000);
```

inside `.then` or check whether some div of your page is exist inside your page like

```
$('#someDiv') !== null
```

Comment: Using a timer in this way is just a "guess" for when other code will be done and should pretty much never be done this way.