# How to store a "jQuery.get" value into a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am making a website that requires for it to read a value from a .txt file(which for testing purposes was set to "8080") to then store that value into a global variable. Here is the code that I'm having issues with:

```
var portTxtFile = "/assets/port.txt";
var portTxtData;
jQuery.get(portTxtFile, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  portTxtData = data;
});
console.log(portTxtData);
```

The console logs were added to test if the variable was really being set. Here are the results of the console logs:[the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU5e7.png)

For some reason, the console is logging the console.log(portTxtData) outside of the jQuery.get function before the console.log(data) that's inside the function. And the variable "portTxtData" is not being set.

I need help setting the variable "portTxtData" to "data" from the "jQuery.get" function.

Comment: Use .ajax() instead of .get() please see the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283276/execute-function-after-ajax-call-is-complete/23283596#23283596

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari — `ajax()` is the same as `get()` but with slightly different defaults. Using it brings no benefit.

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari — That example is dreadful. It uses `async: false` which is known to cause performance problems and which browsers have deprecated.

Comment: @Quentin if you want to run your code that way you have to use async. If you want to do it in `a proper` way I recommend you learning the basics of async functions, function callbacks and ajax. The `console.log(portTxtData);` triggers before the other one because jQuery.get is async

Comment: @Hashim You can avoid async false and perform your action in complete:function().