# Accessing Scope outside http.post request

Tags: php, angularjs

I am posting with AngularJS http.post, putting the response.data into a scope within the successCallback function. console.log writes the scope data but I can't acces the scope data within another function.

Init calls the function for the request.

```
$scope.init = function(group_year_id,year)
{
    accessScopeFunction();
    foo();
};
```

This is the called function

```
function accessScopeFunction() {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/sjb/public/admin/groups/assing/angular/get/databasename'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.getDatabaseName = response.data.event_db;
        console.log($scope.getDatabaseName);            
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        return 'Fault';
    });

};
```

I would like to pass $scope.getDatabaseName to another function

```
function foo() {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/sjb/',
        data: {'databasename':$scope.getDatabaseName}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
};
```

I read a lot about promise, AngularJS documentation, etc but I can't find a proper solution which works for me.

Comment: When and how is `foo()` being called?  How are you guaranteeing that it is called _after_ the request in `accessScopeFunction()` has completed?

Comment: foo() is called after accessScopeFunction() both within Init. Just updated my question.

Comment: That's most likely your problem then.  You're making an _asyncronous_ (the "a" in ajax) request.  Your code fires the request and then keeps going, it doesn't wait for the response.  So your `then` callback in the first request probably isn't happening until _after_ your `foo()` function gets called.

Comment: That explains a lot but what is the correct solution for solving this issue so I can use the $scope.getDatabaseName with a value (now it is undifined) in the foo() function, cause I can't find it

Comment: Call `foo()` in the callback in `accessScopeFunction()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)  The answer in that post is a _very_ good (albeit somewhat long) read.  I highly suggest you take the time to go through it.  For a shorter answer see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283276/execute-function-after-ajax-call-is-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its pretty easy. `$http` returns a `promise`. So use that nice addition to create you own `promises`.

What currently happens at your code is the following:

```
accessScopeFunction();
foo();
```

They are called after each other, so while `accessScopeFunction()` is still processing and waiting to be resolved. `foo()` is also being called. So what you need to do is wait for `accessScopeFunction()` to finish.

You can do this by using the `promise` the `$http` calls are returning:

```
function accessScopeFunction()
{
    var promise = $http(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/sjb/public/admin/groups/assing/angular/get/databasename'
        }
    ).then(
        function successCallback(response)
        {
            $scope.getDatabaseName = response.data.event_db;
            console.log($scope.getDatabaseName);
        },
        function errorCallback(response)
        {
            return 'Fault';
        }
    );

    // Return the promise
    return promise;
};
```

Do the same for `foo()`

```
function foo()
{
    var promise = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/sjb/',
            data: {
                'databasename': $scope.getDatabaseName
            }
        }
    ).then(
        function successCallback(response)
        {

        }, function errorCallback(response)
        {

        }
    );

    return promise;
};
```

Then call `accessScopeFunction()` and use the `then()` callback to call `foo()`

```
$scope.init = function (group_year_id, year)
{
    accessScopeFunction().then(
        function ()
        {
            foo();
        }
    );
};
```

`foo()` can be used the same way.

```
foo().then(function () { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to chain your promises so you can access to the first result in the second function:

```
$scope.init = function(group_year_id,year)
{
  accessScopeFunction().then(foo(databaseName))
};

function accessScopeFunction() {
  return  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/sjb/public/admin/groups/assing/angular/get/databasename'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.getDatabaseName = response.data.event_db;
    return $scope.getDatabaseName;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    return 'Fault';
  });
};

function foo() {

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/sjb/',
    data: {'databasename':$scope.getDatabaseName}
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {

  }, function errorCallback(response) {

  });
};
```