# Simplest solution for Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated and add a waiting circle gif animation while javascript do ajax call to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My current code is :

```
var dataReceiveString = $.ajax({
                    url: "getDataReceiveString.php?"+param,
                    dataType: "text",
                    async: false
                    }).responseText;

// code that make use of dataReceiveString ;
```

The obvious choice of changing false to true does not work.

How should the code be rearranged ?

Also to add a waiting circle gif animation while javascript do ajax call to php.

edit : question is different from [Execute function after Ajax call is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283276/execute-function-after-ajax-call-is-complete)
as avoiding use of async:false.

edit : question is different from
[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
as it's too generic and not targetted to my question.

Comment: Basically add `success: function(data) { /* Do something with your response data */ }` after `async: false, `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it sync you can always rely to `async functions`:

```
    async function doAjax(args) {
        let result;

        try {
            result = await $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: args
            });
            // code that make use of dataReceiveString
            return result;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```