# Execute function after ajax call finished

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know, this was asked several times on SO (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283276/execute-function-after-ajax-call-is-complete)), but nothing worked for me.

I have a JSON Import via ajax. This imports data for a slick slider. So the slick slider should be initialized after the ajax import finished.

My Code:

```
  // Import Ticker
  $.ajax({
      url: '/de/data/data.json',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json'
  }).success(function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var obj = data[i];
          $('section.ticker .slider').append(`
            <div class="slide">1</div>
            <div class="slide">2</div>
            <div class="slide">3</div>
          `)};

      $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $('.slider').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });
      });

      // Error handler
      }).error(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
      })
```

I also tried:

```
  }).success(function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var obj = data[i];
          $('section.ticker .slider').append(`
            <div class="slide">1</div>
            ...
          `)};
      }.complete: function (data) {
        $('.slider').slick({
          infinite: ...
        });
      }).error(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
      })
```

Or this:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
     infinite: ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure, but I would start with having `$(document).on('ready' ...` and then put ajax call inside it. Then, after for loop is finished I would place $('.slider').slick( ... )

Comment: Why did you choose to use `$(document).on('ready', ...)` inside the `success` of the ajax call in your first example? Is there a reason not to have the `.slick()` call run immediately after the loop appends the `.slide` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove slick initialisation from `$(document).on('ready',function(){});`

Your code will look like

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/de/data/data.json',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json'
  }).success(function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var obj = data[i];
          $('section.ticker .slider').append(`
            <div class="slide">1</div>
            <div class="slide">2</div>
            <div class="slide">3</div>
          `)};

        $('.slider').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });

      // Error handler
      }).error(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
  })
```