# jQuery timing of ajaxSuccess/ajaxError versus ajaxComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this and [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) doesn't exactly make it clear.

From what I understand, and from what [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021078/477563) have mentioned, the global `ajaxComplete` event occurs after the global `ajaxSuccess` or `ajaxError` events.

That being said, what is the timing relationship between those two sets of events?

- Is `ajaxComplete` simply guaranteed to start after `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxError` have started?
- Is `ajaxComplete` guaranteed to start once `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxError` have completed?
- No guarantees?

As a bit of background, I'm trying to ensure that my `ajaxComplete` handler doesn't run until after the `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxError` handlers complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ajaxComplete` triggers after the **completion** of `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxError` handlers.

Here's the relevant code from jQuery 2.1.4 (which is also the same in jQuery 1.11.3):

```
// Status-dependent callbacks
jqXHR.statusCode( statusCode );
statusCode = undefined;

if ( fireGlobals ) {
    globalEventContext.trigger( isSuccess ? "ajaxSuccess" : "ajaxError",
        [ jqXHR, s, isSuccess ? success : error ] );
}

// Complete
completeDeferred.fireWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText ] );

if ( fireGlobals ) {
    globalEventContext.trigger( "ajaxComplete", [ jqXHR, s ] );
    // Handle the global AJAX counter
    if ( !( --jQuery.active ) ) {
        jQuery.event.trigger("ajaxStop");
    }
}
```

---

To verify that it, I set up an experiment where I could arbitrarily specify how long the `ajaxSuccess` handler would take to complete.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function (e, xhr, settings) {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    // Intentionally waste an arbitrary length of time
    while ( (new Date()).getTime() - startTime < 1000 ) { }

    var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log('ajaxSuccess\n'
              + '    Start: ' + startTime + '\n'
              + '    End:   ' + endTime
    );
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log('ajaxComplete\n'
              + '    Start: ' + startTime
    );
});

$.get('/');
```

The experiment confirmed what I had previously observed, namely that `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxError` always finish before `ajaxComplete` even starts, regardless of how long it took.

Answer (score 0):

### The documentation for this is found [here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

---

### From the documentation:

> **Events**
>
> This is the full list of Ajax events, and in the order in which they
>   are triggered. The indented events are triggered for each and every
>   Ajax request (unless a global option has been set). The ajaxStart and
>   ajaxStop events are events that relate to all Ajax requests together.
>
> - ajaxStart (Global Event): This event is triggered if an Ajax
>     request is started and no other Ajax requests are currently running.
>
>   - beforeSend (Local Event): This event, which is triggered before an Ajax request is started, allows you to modify the XMLHttpRequest
>       object (setting additional headers, if need be.)
>   - ajaxSend (Global
>       Event): This global event is also triggered before the request is run.
>   - success (Local Event): This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).
>   - ajaxSuccess (Global Event): This event is also only called if the
>       request was successful.
>   - error (Local Event): This event is only called if an error occurred with the request (you can never have both an error and a success callback with a request).
>   - ajaxError (Global Event): This global event behaves the same as the local error event.
>   - complete (Local Event): This event is called regardless of if the request was successful, or not. You will always receive a complete callback, even for synchronous requests.
>   - ajaxComplete (Global Event): This event behaves the same as the complete event and will be triggered every time an Ajax request finishes.
> - ajaxStop (Global Event): This global event is triggered if there are no more Ajax requests being processed.

Comment: That's well and all, but that still doesn't answer my question.  I understand and accept that `ajaxComplete` will trigger **after** `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxError`, but does "after" entail "after they've *started*" or "after they've *completed*"?