# jquery code inside .ajaxComplete fires multiple times but should only do once

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have 4 page loader functions that autoloads html filled with data from a database with ajax post  inside a div (for each of those functions i have a own div ) when the user scrolls down. now in this received htmldata i want to have a onclick event and do some more ajax post actions to manipulate some of the data and display the change.

but when i use

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
$("#clickelement").click(function(){
//do some ajax post here and fill a div with the received data
});
```

the click functions is executet  4 times (since there are 4 ajax post actions before. and when i click again its executet 5 times (i think the ajax action inside the onclick trigger also the .ajaxComplete ) and additionally when i scroll down to load more data its executed even more.. how can i get around this and fire the .click only once and have the click function active on all #clickelement divs inside the autoloaded html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i solved it now for those who are interested:

```
$('#divwhichisfilledwithajax').on('click', '#clickelement', function () {
//do what the click on the #clickelement should do
});
```

ive searched a while and found out that i can use delegated event listeners. i think with this method it will piling up listeners after every AJAX call since im not targetting only the new elements but all of the previous ones as well. and additionally it will only fire once. since the listeners are only added to the newly loaded elements which fit the argument #clickelement

simple and clean :)

Answer (score 3):

You are adding your code to the global `ajaxComplete` event. This means that it will be called any time an ajax call completes.

> ajaxComplete (Global Event)
>   This event behaves the same as the complete event and will be triggered every time an Ajax request finishes.
>   [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

[Better docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

What you are probably looking for is the `success` or `complete` callbacks which are *local* events (fired only on that specific ajax call) and are used like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: {},
  dataType: 'text',
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: APP_URL + '/extension/ad/get-user-attributes/' + email,
  success: function(response) {
     // fires when THIS ajax request returns successfully
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
    // fires when THIS ajax request returns an error
  },
  complete: function(xhr, status) {
     // fires when THIS ajax request completes (after success or error)
  }
});
```

For the difference between `complete` and `success` [see this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021078/1376624)

Comment: its working, ive put the .click functions in its own function and then i execute this function in the success sections of the ajax post function.. but when i now scroll down ( more data gets loaded and the same function in the success sections is triggered now twice now so the .click code is fired two times, but only on the first loaded data..

Comment: We'd need to see all the code that does those things. What you've shown here wouldnt do any of that, there must be something else going on, but wee need to see it

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and came across the solution (Forgot where)

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
//Change it to delegated event listener with addition '.off()'
$("#ParentDivOfAjaxContents").off().on('click', '#clickelement', function () {
//do anything you want after the click on'#clickelement'

});
});
```

Hope it helps anyone who has the same issue.