# Post data using ajax and then go to that page with posted data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem i have to post 2 Ajax request at the same time. I have post data to one file and return response and then post to other page and then go to that page with posted data so i can access by using $_post on next page and show the values.

i have tried some redirect request but none of them works. windows opens but no value is posted $_post is empty. i want to go to the addproduct.fr.php page after the values are posted with posted values.

```
type: 'POST',
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
data: data,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
cache: false,
timeout: 600000,
url: 'filecreate.php',
success: function(response) { alert(response); },

type: 'POST',
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
url: 'addproduct.fr.php',
data: data,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
cache: false,
timeout: 600000,
success: function(response) { alert(response); },
```

Comment: you need to use ajax complete method.means when first request completed then only execute second.:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021062/use-success-or-complete-in-ajax-call

Comment: can you show me some code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your requirement can be split into two phases:

1. To post data and get the response back.
2. To again post data and go to another page with the posted Data.

**Solution:**

For the first case use Ajax, and on return success for second case you can go for a postback or form submit instead of Ajax.

You can store the data returned using Ajax in one of the hidden textbox (provided the data is limited and not very big enough) and then do a form submit with method POST using JavaScript.