# Access JsonResult in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have an ajax call which returns the following method in my razor page model:

```
return new JsonResult(new { success = "false", data = "Invalid model state error." });
```

This returns the following result to the client side:

> {"$id":"1","success":"false","data":"Invalid model state error."}

However I am struggling to get access to the values in Jquery.  Here is what I have tried:

```
function onCompleted(result) {
  alert(result.success); 
  alert(result[0].success);       
}
```

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
>       at HTMLFormElement.onCompleted

Ajax syntax as requested:

```
<form asp-page="./MultiEdit" asp-page-handler="CreateInvoiceItem" id="formInvoiceItem"
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="post"
      data-ajax-complete="onCompleted"
      data-ajax-failed="onFailed">
      ....
</form>
```

Watch:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your full `$.ajax` syntax? Shouldn't it be `onComplete`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021062/

Comment: @DaveAnderson code added as requested,  I have it defined as `onCompleted`.  The onCompleted method runs, I just cant get access to the result.

Comment: console.log(result) and tell us if is really a json object or xhr , if is not json object
you will need to get the value and give it a variable and use something like JSON.stringify to make it json and access the key / value variablename.success

Comment: Be careful as `responseJson` will be undefined, the correct property is `responseJSON`. Glad you've found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery Unbotrusive AJAX Callback](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax#callback-functions) returns an jqXHR;

> When an AJAX request is made using jQuery, a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object is returned.
>   This is made available to callback functions that you specify via the
>   `data-ajax-complete`, `data-ajax-success` and `data-ajax-failure`
>   attributes.

Assuming the `Content-Type` of the response is `json` then the [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) should have a `responseJSON` property.

> If `json` is specified, the response is parsed using [jQuery.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
>   before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed
>   JSON object is made available through the `responseJSON` property of the
>   `jqXHR` object.

The following should give you the status and message from your response;

```
function onCompleted(xhr) {
  alert(xhr.reponseJSON.success); 
  alert(xhr.reponseJSON.data);       
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the following error:  `Cannot read property 'success' of undefined  at HTMLFormElement.onCompleted`

Comment: Can you add a break point in dev tools and see what properties the `xhr` does have? It should at least include `responseXML` or `responseText`.

Comment: I haven't been able to get client side debugging working as yet.  I will try.

Comment: Ok, it has responseJSON is `Object {$id: "1", success: true, data: Object}`

Comment: And the responseText  is `"{"$id":"1","success":true,"data":{"$id":"2","InvoiceItemID":0......`

Comment: So `responseJSON.success` should be `true`? The `responseText` will have been passed to `parseJSON` which created `responseJSON` with a property `data` which is another Object. `responseJSON.data.InvoiceItemID` should be `0`. So you have access to these now in your function where you have the break point?

Comment: No something weird is still going on, I can access the xhr variable but not xhr.responseJson which is undefined.  See the attached image above.

Comment: You need to access it with [property dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) i.e. `xhr.responseJSON`. The parameter to the callback function is `xhr` and it has the `responseJSON` object as a property and that object has a property `success`. The callback function I have in my answer should work with `xhr.reponseJSON.success`.

Comment: I am definitely using the dot notation.  On `xhr.reponseJSON.success`  I get responseJson is undefined.

Comment: I also tried setting it to a variable `var x = xhr.responseJson;`  and I again get undefined.  See image attached.

Comment: The solution was to use `data-ajax-success` instead of `data-ajax-complete`, this gave me direct access to my success variable `function onSuccess(result) { alert(result.success);}`  Trying to access the variable through xhr.responseJson.success in the complete callback did not work.

Comment: Your last comment nailed it,  I was incorrectly using `responseJson` instead of `responseJSON`.  Thanks for your help.