# Data inserted successfully but no jquery success returned

Tags: php, ajax

I developed an application and in which I am inserting some records by using the service. The data is successfully inserted but the problem is my success function is not working.

What is wrong with my code?

```
    $('#editdonorForm').on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/goods_campaign/update_conn.php",
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#updateDonor').val("Updating");
   },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#editdonorForm').reset();
        $('#update').modal('hide');
        swal({
            title: "Donor Updated",
            text: response.message,
            icon: "success",
            button: "Done"
         });
         donorTable.ajax.reload();
    },
    error: function(error){
      alert(error);
    } 
    });
});
```

Comment: First follow-up Question: if you remove the swal() block and replace it by `alert('success');` what happens ?

Comment: It still has the same output as before even though I already set my response `if($query_run2){
    echo 'Donor Information is Updated Successfully!'; 
}` in my PHP URL file. @KenLee

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021062/use-success-or-complete-in-ajax-call/42229704

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax code is good, but if you want calling success function ajax your request must return response status code 200 or 201 it's mean OK, but if not its will call error function ajax.